# does ARM7 in LPC2103 not support CLZ?

Tags: assembly, embedded, arm, gnu-toolchain

I've only been Googling for a couple hours or so, but if someone has a quick answer to this I'd like to get back to programming. Here's my error:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/rentacoder/jcomeau/armmite$ make
/usr/local/bin/preasm.tcl minimal.asm minimal.s 
"/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/as" -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -mapcs-32 \
     -gstabs -ahls=minimal.lst  -o minimal.o minimal.s
minimal.s: Assembler messages:
minimal.s:183: Error: selected processor does not support `clz r0,r0'
make: *** [minimal.o] Error 1
rm minimal.s
```

I've tried with -mcpu=arm7tdmi as well, which is what Coridium uses for their code for the ARMmite v.2, the board I'm using. But they apparently don't have any clz instructions in their code. My question is, *should* it work, and it's just that my assembler doesn't realize it, or does this chip really not implement CLZ?

[update: according to http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3974.htm, arm7tdmi-s is the correct architecture specification]

[further update: I coded the instruction manually with `.word 0xe16f0f10` and instead of the expected undefined instruction error I got a data abort. strange.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CLZ` instruction was introduced in ARMv5. The ARM7TDMI and ARM9 do not have this instruction.

Comment: okay thanks. my mistaken assumption was that ARM7 meant ARMv7.

Comment: That is a common source of confusion, yes.

Comment: ARM "family" names and ARM "architecture" version numbers are not directly related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARM_cores

Comment: From the technical referece manual for the ARM7TDMI:  The ARM7TDMI processor is an implementation of the ARMv4T architecture. For full details of both the ARM and Thumb instruction sets, see the ARM Architecture Reference Manual.

Comment: Then the ARM ARM under CLZ says: Architecture version: Version 5 and above.  If you look at the AND instruction for example (ands) you can set or clear the Z flag (granted the other flags are also affected).

Comment: @dwelch, note that `CLZ` is Count Leading Zeros, not CLear Zero flag. :)